# Loop a single track/element in a XSPF playlist using VLC

Tags: vlc-media-player

I've googled a lot, but I haven't found a solution yet.

Is it possible to loop a single track in the XSPF playlist?

In terms of a pause, we can do it in a xspf playlist as follows:

```
<track>
   <location>vlc://pause:10</location>
   <extension application="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/0">
     <vlc:id>1</vlc:id>
   </extension>
</track>
```

Is there anything similar to loop a track?

With CLI VLC it is possible to loop a given number of times:

```
cvlc Example.mp4 :input-repeat=3
```

So I think it can be done using a XSPF playlist.

Please someone enlighten me with wisdom and knowledge to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**And the trick is**

for infinit loop:

```
<vlc:option>input-repeat=-1</vlc:option>
```

To repeat 3x

```
<vlc:option>input-repeat=3</vlc:option>
```

just like the command line...

Comment: Many months later, the answer has finally arrived =D THANKS!!!! Just one clarification: `input-repeat=3` will repeat the track FOUR times, not three. So to repeat a track three times we use `2`. Thanks for your help =D =)

Comment: So, for the 2018 year you cannot add the negative value of `"input-repeat"`
to the XSPF playlist. Your string must look like `<vlc:option>input-repeat=65545</vlc:option>` References to the issue - https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/issues/96

Answer (score 0):

Wiki lists this as a way to set an option (within the `extension` data element): `<vlc:option>stop-time=55</vlc:option>`.

Some VLC playlist options:

```
--random plays files randomly forever.
--loop loops playlist on end.
--repeat repeats current item until another item is forced
--play-and-stop stops the playlist after each played item.
```

So maybe try adding: `<vlc:option>repeat</vlc:option>`

Comment: Mmm... Sadly no, it won't repeat that way =/ But your answer seems useful, thanks! I'll read more, maybe I'll get something! Let's wait another answer in hopes someone else knows the exact way to do this =) Thanks ;)

Comment: I've read but the specification says those options you mention are for playlists indeed but they're not applied as vlc:options like `stop-time=55` Those are for tracks. But the playlist ones are only used in a command line code =\